# in unity I cannot create double jump in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to create double jump. But i think there is something wrong in the code.
here i tried to use jump  count as but as soon as i try to jump the value quickly turns into 2 after being 1 for a brief second. i dont see where i went wrong. I am a beginner in unity and dont understand some certain stuff.

````
{
    public float MovementSpeed;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator ani;
    SpriteRenderer sp;
    public Transform check;
    private bool grounded;
    private int jump;
    public LayerMask layer;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        ani = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sp = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(check.position, 0.1f, layer);
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(MovementSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            if (grounded == true)
            {
                ani.Play("Run");
            }
            else
            {
                ani.Play("Jump");
            }
            sp.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-MovementSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            if (grounded == true)
            {
                ani.Play("Run");
            }
            else
            {
                ani.Play("Jump");
            }
            sp.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (grounded == true)
            {
                ani.Play("Idle");
            }
            else
            {
                ani.Play("Jump");
            }
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (grounded == true)
        {
            jump = 0;
        }
        if (jump < 2 && Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 2);
            ani.Play("Jump");
            jump++;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("space") && jump == 0 && grounded == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 4);
            ani.Play("Jump");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: note that `if (grounded == true)` is redundant and can be simplified by `if (grounded)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
        if (jump < 2 && Input.GetKey("space"))
```

When `jump` is 0, your program work as intended: since `jump` is smaller than 2 and space key is pressed, jump will increment.

The problem is that in next frame, `jump` is still smaller than 2 and space key is probably pressed, since player usually don't press space bar for exactly one frame.

`GetKey` method returns if button is being pressed right now. As long as you're pressing the button, it will return true.

Because so second jump will be handled instantly. To fix this problem, use `GetKeyDown` instead of `GetKey`.

```cs
        if (jump < 2 && Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
```

`GetKeyDown`, unlike `GetKey`, checks if button began being pressed in this frame.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. There were some other mistakes in my codes. I am still new to unity and I have learned a lot of stuff from you.